# Fill all divs, even when the array is too short

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a WordPress site using Bootstrap. I want to get the first three posts in a category, then loop through them and put all three in a single row.

The trouble is that when a category has only one or two posts the layout is broken, because no markup for the div is written to the page.

```
<div class="row">
<?php
  foreach(array_slice($posts_array, 0, 3) as $post):
?>      
  <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
  </div>
<?php
   endforeach; 
?>
</div>
```

I need this to generate

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <img src=image.jpg">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <img src=image2.jpg">
    Second Title
  </div>
 <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <img src=image3.jpg">
    Third Title
  </div>
</div>
```

But if a category only has two posts then I get

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <img src=image.jpg">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <img src=image2.jpg">
    Second Title
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure this can't be too hard, but my brain doesn't seem to be working. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
<div class="row">
 <?php
    $val = 3;
    $i = 1;
    foreach(array_slice($posts_array, 0, $val) as $post):
 ?>      
   <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
   </div>
 <?php
    $i++; endforeach; 
 ?>

 <?php for ($j = 0; $j < ($val - $i); $j++) { ?>
     // Your Extra Divs.
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Count the array, try and see if `$count % 3 == 0`, if not, add fake array elements onto the end, and in your code, just check for something in the fake array that shows it is a real row or not, then you can display a blank box or whatever for the remaining elements.

The other way is starting $x = 1, and incremementing within the loop.